# Failed to enqueue tests.: An unknown exception occurred

Tags: apex, unit-test, execute-anonymous

While running unit Tests in my Sandbox, i got the Following Error and i cannot continue with tests. 
Message is:

Failed to enqueue tests.: An unknown exception occurred.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the given error message is that maximum amount of unit tests executions per 24 hours is reached.

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_run_tests.htm&type=5):

> The maximum number of test classes you can run per 24-hour period is
>   the greater of 500 or 10 multiplied by the number of test classes in
>   the org. For sandbox and Developer Edition organizations, this limit
>   is the greater of 500 or 20 multiplied by the number of test classes
>   in the org.

One of the approaches could be to clone a sandbox (if there are unused licenses of same type) and run tests there.

Comment: Thank you so much. Have a good day!

Comment: Any idea how to check your current test limit? and to see the time when it will be reset?